# Proof of inequality for function sum

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Is there a simpler solution to this problem? More importantly, is this correct?
We have a function $f(x) = \sqrt{ x^TQx }$ that acts on a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with a symmetric positive definite matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. Show that:
\begin{gather*}
\text{with } s_{1,k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k}s_i \\
\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(s_i) \geq f(s_{1,n})
\end{gather*}
Assuming that $f(a) + f(b) \geq f(a+b)$ we can show:
\begin{gather*}
f(s_{1,n-1}) + f(s_n) \geq f(s_{1,n}) \\
f(s_{1,n-2}) + f(s_{n-1}) \geq f(s_{1,n-1}) \\
\dots \\
f(s_1) + f(s_2) \geq f(s_{1,2})
\end{gather*}
Which implies that the claim is true. We can prove our assumption by noting that $f(x) \geq 0$ and writing the inequality as:
\begin{align*}
(f(a) + f(b))^2 &\geq f(a+b)^2 \\
f(a)^2 + f(b)^2 + 2f(a)f(b) &\geq f(a+b)^2 \\
a^TQa + b^TQb + 2\sqrt{(a^TQa)(b^TQb)} &\geq (a+b)^TQ(a+b) \\
&\geq a^TQa + b^TQb + a^TQb + b^TQa \\
\sqrt{(a^TQa)(b^TQb)} &\geq a^TQb
\end{align*}
The left hand side is always positive and the right hand side is either negative or we need:
\begin{gather*}
(a^TQa)(b^TQb) \geq (a^TQb)^2
\end{gather*}
Which is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality because $Q$ is symmetric positive definite and the operation $a^TQb$ has all the properties of an inner product.

Comment: As you observed, $a^TQb$ is an inner product, so that $\sqrt{a^TQa}$ is a norm and what you proved is the triangle inequality, which can be taken for granted as much as Cauchy-Schwarz.